# I want to delete selected contact number from phone call log and list view but this code not working

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Number removed from list item and application also ask permission but number does not remove from the mobile call logs.
How to refresh call-logs? so that selected contact number from phone call log are deleted.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.create();
    android.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
    dialog.setMessage("Are you sure, you want to Delete ");
    dialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            CharSequence name = aList.get(position).get("listview_number");
            String queryString = "NUMBER=" + name;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "  Number: " +name+ " Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            aList.remove(position);
            simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


    });
    dialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Dont Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: do you get toast message? can you try hardcoding some number in and write this in main onCreate method getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);

Comment: thansk for help